# Problem in trigonometry integral

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{1}{(9-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$

Let $x=3\sin (u)$

$dx=3\cos (u)$

So, $(9-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}=(9-9\sin ^2(u))^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$=27\cos ^3(u)$

$u=\sin ^-1(\frac{x}{3})$

My problem is how to substitute u into the integral to become $3\int \frac{\sec ^2(u)}{27}$du?

Comment: Just to add: $$\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}=|\cos u|$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your substitutions:

$$
\int \frac{dx}{(9 - x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \;\; =\;\; \int \frac{3 \cos u du}{27(1- \sin^2u)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{9} \int\frac{\cos u}{\cos^3u} du \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{9} \int \frac{du}{\cos^2u}.
$$

Now use the fact that $\sec u = \frac{1}{\cos u}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much there.

$\int \frac{1}{(9-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx = \int \frac{3\cos u}{27 cos^3 u}du = \frac{1}{9}\int \sec^2 u \; du$

Comment: This kinda goes against the rules of the site but I'm just gonna say it anyway:  You have the best username.

Comment: Haha. I didn't know such rules existed.  Thank you though. @Mnifldz